# What is the correct syntax for ALTER TABLE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add a simple column in my table in MySQL but it is giving syntax error:

> Error Code: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
ADD classname VARCHAR 150 NULL AFTER id;
```

Comment: As a pointer for your next question: mysql tells you where the syntax error occured in the statement, so next time share that part with us as well.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
ADD classname VARCHAR(150) NULL AFTER id;
```

Comment: Thanks some time minor issues create big problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

The length of the varchar type must be enclosed by brackets:

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
ADD classname VARCHAR(150) NULL AFTER id;
```

Answer (score 3):

the length of a field n sql must be enclosed with (),but you have missed the paranthesis(),so you were getting the error,just try with ()

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
ADD classname VARCHAR(150) NULL AFTER id;
```

Answer (score 2):

extra parenthesis is required for datatype

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
ADD classname VARCHAR(150) NULL AFTER id;
```